# Cut and Compress 4K Video?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, compression, video-conversion, video-editing

I have a 20 second video which size in 4K which size is 125 MB. 
It is only about a defective electronic component so accuracy is not important. I want it much smaller. 
I have these options in VLC

[image]

I have tried now most of the video formats and viewed them

- .webm cuts the video and loses the sound
- unsuccessful with .asf (no video remains, cutting) and .ts (no video remains, only 1 second of sound)

However, the compression takes quite a much time, and also I am not sure which format is best for my players QuickTime and VLC.

It would be also nice to cut the video fast because it would also decrease the video size. 
I have systems OS X, Linux Ubuntu, and Windows 10. I share the original file by BTsync easily through all systems so I can edit anywhere.

---

Which video format is enough compressed in VLC?

Comment: Use H.264 and scale it down to 1080p. This will take a short while to re-encode.

Comment: @Linef4ult Excellent! So bitrate = 1080. There are scaling options in VLC where you can also select scale to 0.25 which reduced the video size to 0.25, reducing file size to 5.2 Mb. Make your answer an answer so I will accept it. Cutting is most probably best to in some other application later.

Comment: Bitrate at AUTO if its an option, set scaling to 0.5 and you'll get a decent resolution (Depends on if its real 4k or 3.8k)

Comment: @Linef4ult How is the bitrate = AUTO working? It would be nice to understand its internals.

Comment: H.264 uses target "quality" settings, it sets the bitrate based on an algorithm that is beyond me to explain. It can be clever as a scene with a man running needs a much larger amount of data than say a title screen with just black and some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an h264 mp4 file - Use Handbrake. It'll be compliant with YouTube, Vimeo and 95% of existing media players and smart TVs, smart phones etc etc.

Forget every other file type and every other codec.
If you drop to 1080p then set a bitrate between 2 and 4 Mbps. This will probably cover any eventuality in terms of image quality.